# Careers 2.0 search: filter for listings with an "apply now" button

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'm too lazy to follow external application links and fill in all the info over and over again.

There should be a way to filter the search results to positions for which an application can be made directly through the Careers 2.0 website.

Answer (score 4):

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/applyonly

Comment: Well isn't that handy!

Comment: Nice!  Although the `refine search` drops the filter, you could insert `/applyonly` after `jobs`, but it'd be nice if `refine search` worked properly as-is.